# Fill javascript object with form data

Tags: javascript

I have an object declared, and I have an html form with some matching fields. 
All fields in the form are in the object, but the object also has a couple of additional variables and functions.

I'd like to fill the object with the data entered in the form, what I'm trying right now overwrites the declared object, and so doesn't have the functions nor the other variables.

The object :

```
var Container = {
nodes: [],
Contains: function (Node) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
        if (this.nodes[i].nodeID === Node.nodeID)
            return (i);
    }
    return (-1);
}
```

How I fill it from the form :

```
const handleContainerForm = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  ContainerFormToJSON(form.elements);

  var i = JSONData.Contains(Container);
  if (i === -1)
      JSONData.containers.push(Container);
  else
      JSONData.container[i] = Container;
  output = JSON.stringify(JSONData, null, "  ");

  displayContents(output);
};
```

The form has ID, Title, Folder, Image and Description as fields, so this last `Container` object doesn't have the `Contains()` function nor the `nodes[]` array.

How do I end up with a complete, filled version of the object I have declared ?

Comment: This kind of problem looks so trivial with tools like Angular. It's not even a problem at all. Vanilla JS is so low-level for this kind of things. It's not an answer or even a hint, but I just wanted to say that :)

Comment: @JeremyThille Great, thanks for letting me know, I guess :/

Comment: What does `elements` look like, at what exactly should the result be? Obviously, `Container = ...` will overwrite the variable.

Comment: @Saryk you're welcome :) I can't imagine a company-level, production project written entirely in pure low-level JS without framework or platform (Angular, React... or even just jQuery)

Comment: I guess that the `name` properties of the elements are called `containerID`, `containerTitle`, and so on, am I right? But `ContainerFormToJSON` doesn't return JSON, it just sets the properties. Please explain more clearly what you want to achieve. I don't think you need any third party library or framework.

Comment: @PeterMader I don't want a third party library ;) 
I am not used to js and to be honest it's angering me by the minute, I'm used to C# where I can declare a class and instantiate an object that will have all properties of the class, even if they're not set. That's what I tried to achieve, declare a `Container` class and instantiate a `Container` with the values from the form ; and then serialize it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In **ContainerFormToJSON** function, before the statement

```
return Container
```

define:

```
//container.nodes and container.contains
```

Comment: By Define, you mean `container.nodes = [];` ?

Comment: how do I define the function ?

Comment: Also, `return Container` is in some sort of `foreach` loop, but with a weird syntax which to be honest I don't understand fully... It wouldn't be clean to set them at every passing of the loop...

Answer (score 0):

You are right, JavaScript is very different from C#, especially in regards to OOP. But that doesn't make it better or worse.

In JavaScript, you don't need to declare an object's properties, like you have to when you use classes. I think that you only want to serialize the form's input values to JSON. I recommend not to use an object that additionally has a `nodes` property and a `Contains` method.

If you need to keep a copy of the unserialized object, create two objects:

```js
class Container {
  constructor () {
    this.nodes = [];
  }
  indexOf (node) {
    return this.nodes.findIndex(n => n.nodeID === node.nodeID);
  }
}
Container.nodeID = 0; // think of it as a static property

function extractValues (elements) {
  // 'elements' is an array of <input> elements
  // the 'container' will be filled and serialized
  var container = new Container();
  for (var index in elements) {
    var element = elements[index];
    container[element.name] = element.value;
  }
  container.nodeID = Container.nodeID++; // give the container a unique ID
  return container;
}

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var jsonData = new Container();

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var newContainer = extractValues(inputs);
  var index = jsonData.indexOf(newContainer);
  if (index === -1) {
    jsonData.nodes.push(newContainer);
  } else {
    jsonData.nodes[index] = newContainer;
  }
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, ' ');
  console.log(jsonString);
});
```

```html
<input name="containerID">
<input name="containerTitle">
<!-- ... -->
<button>Serialize</button>
```

Please note: only setting an object's properties doesn't make it to JSON. It's only JSON if it's serialized to a string. I recommend [this](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) article. To serialize a JavaScript object, use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

#### Edit:

Looking at the edit of your question, I think it might be preferable to create a `Container` class. Both `jsonData` and the containers of the form data will be instances of that class. It can contain other containers (`nodes`), and can get the index of such a nested container using the `indexOf` method. I implemented this in the above code snippet. Whenever you hit the "Serialize" button, a new container with the current `<input>`s' contents will be added to `jsonData`. The JSON form of `jsonData` will be logged to the console.

I hope this is what you are looking for. To better understand JavaScript OOP, 
take a look at some of the articles at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects).

Comment: The `nodes[]` array has to be serialized to JSON.
I have a second form to add nodes to the container.

Comment: But I can just define a nodes array before returning the object :) I think your code might do the job :D

Comment: OK, I added the `nodes` array.

Comment: Why bother usung the `object` object ? can't we just bypass it and write directy `container[element.name] = element.value;` ? or is it a typo and you meant `object[element.name] = element.value;` ? :p

Comment: No typo. You can't have methods in JSON, and I didn't want to rely on `JSON.stringify` to silently skip the method. After some research however, it turns out that the second object is not necessary.

Comment: Does the error occur in the SO snippet or in your code? The SO snippet works for me. Is `elements` really an array?

Comment: I have updated my Question with one last thing : I have an object called `JSONData` that only holds an array of `Containers[]` and a `Contains()` function that's the same as the one in the `Container` object.

When I check if the `JSONData.containers[]` contains a new `Container`, it updates the previous one before checking. Does `JSONData.containers.push(Container);` not push a copy of the `Container` we use to the array but a reference to the original ?